# Javascript's indexOf shim clarification?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I saw [**at mdn**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) the code which should  be used - if there is no `indexOf` implementation .

*This algorithm matches the one specified in ECMA-262* ... as they say

And here is the code :

```
/*1*/   if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
/*2*/     Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement , fromIndex) {
/*3*/       var i,
/*4*/           pivot = (fromIndex) ? fromIndex : 0,
/*5*/           length;
/*6*/   
/*7*/       if (!this) {
/*8*/         throw new TypeError();
/*9*/       }
/*10*/   
/*11*/       length = this.length;
/*12*/   
/*13*/       if (length === 0 || pivot >= length) {
/*14*/         return -1;
/*15*/       }
/*16*/   
/*17*/       if (pivot < 0) {
/*18*/         pivot = length - Math.abs(pivot);
/*19*/       }
/*20*/   
/*21*/       for (i = pivot; i < length; i++) {
/*22*/         if (this[i] === searchElement) {
/*23*/           return i;
/*24*/         }
/*25*/       }
/*26*/       return -1;
/*27*/     };
/*28*/   }
```

But my question is about line #7 :

If I write :

`[].indexOf` then  - `this` is the array itself. ( Heck , it is attached to `Array.prototype.indexOf` - at first place).

I mean - `this` will always be truthy value. so **why** does this check exist ?

Also - Resharper shows me this ( which is perfectly logical) :

[image]

So - why does this check exist? Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not necessarily -- it's because the `indexOf()` native function uses the direct `this` value passed, not the one converted to an object (equivalent to what happens in strict mode), and such a shim would need to check for this to be compliant. For example, this code will throw a `TypeError`:

```
var a = Array.prototype.indexOf;
a();
```

It will throw a `TypeError`, as the `this` value is not converted into an object or changed to the global object. In user-defined non-strict functions, the value of `this` is the global object if there is no parent object, but in ES5 strict mode it is passed as `undefined` itself. Another situation is when you call it specifically with either `null` or `undefined`:

```
"use strict";
Array.prototype.indexOf.call(null); // TypeError, what else can we do?
```

In the ES5 specification, *the **this** value* refers to the original value passed as the `thisArg`, without any changes. In non-strict mode, *the **this** value* is not accessible to code in user-defined functions, but native functions are able to explicitly specify use of *the **this** value* instead of what the `this` keyword evaluates to (which is referred to as the `ThisBinding` in the specification). In strict mode, they both evaluate to the same thing.

Because the native version is able to access the non-boxed version of the `this` value in non-strict mode (which is directly passed to the internal function `[[ToObject]]`, which throws a `TypeError` upon attempting to convert `null` or `undefined`), this check needs to implemented to satisfy the requirements of the specification.

Note: technically, the code sample in your question isn't *quite* by the ES5 specification, as the `this` value could be falsy, which would fail it even though it should proceed in theory (native implementations of `indexOf()` do not throw if `false` is passed as the `this` value). As well, since the global object would be passed if *the this value* was actually undefined or null, it would pass the `if (!this)` test, even when it's not supposed to. This cannot be solved simply by checking that the argument is not the global object, because this would fail if the global object was explicitly passed (which is permitted).

Comment: Also if you call it with `.call()` or `.apply()` and specify a falsy value as the first parameter.

Comment: @Cuberto: though `0` or `false` will be converted to their object equivalents.

Comment: So the problem is only with strict mode ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - it's also happen in normal mode (if I test it properly...)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Note that `this` can be set to `0` or `false` without object-boxing in strict mode. (But in non-strict, they do indeed get object-ified.)

Comment: @RoyiNamir `> Array.prototype.indexOf.call(null)
TypeError: Array.prototype.indexOf called on null or undefined`

called from console without setting "strict" mode first...

Comment: @codename-: that's because the native functions are able to get the values passed without boxing, even in non-strict mode.

Comment: @RoyiNamir To clarify, that seems to be testing the *native* `indexOf`, not the shim supplied in the question.

Comment: I always said : "Resharper - mind your own .net business and leave js alone :-)"